# Remove Column Header from DataTable When tranposed

Tags: c#

In the function below I try to get the transpose of any given `datatable`. But if the input table has no row headers it adds the first column of the input table as the column headers of the output table which is wrong. How can I get rid of the **column headers** in the output table?

```
public DataTable generatetranspose(DataTable inputtable)
{
    DataTable outputtable = new DataTable();

    outputtable.Columns.Add(inputtable.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString());

    foreach (DataRow inrow in inputtable.Rows)
    {
        string newcol = inrow[0].ToString();
        outputtable.Columns.Add(newcol);
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i <= inputtable.Columns.Count - 1 ; i++ )
    {
        DataRow newrow = outputtable.NewRow();
        newrow[0] = inputtable.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
        for(int j =0 ; j <= inputtable.Rows.Count - 1 ; j++)
        {
            string colvalue = inputtable.Rows[j][i].ToString();
            newrow[j + 1] = colvalue;
        }
        outputtable.Rows.Add(newrow);
    }

    return outputtable;
}
```

Comment: @rene No that will just remove the first column from the output table

Comment: What do you mean transpose? What do you want to achieve with generatetranspose()?

Comment: @jomsk1e Its simple , for example 3x2 datatable to a 2x3 one